# wxPython -- StaticBox Sizer resizing Static Boxes, and adding a box?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have a for loop that creates one static box for each node in a dictionary and it puts them all in a panel, 3 to a row max, and spaced apart.  Now I want to add text inside each static box, but when I went to do that, it shrunk the boxes, put them side by side off-center, and added an extra box to the end with nothing in it.  I commented out the lines that caused this issue:

```
nodeSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    rowSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    nodeSizer.AddSpacer((0,25))
    rowSizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
    for index, (key, value) in enumerate(self.addArgs["khzObj"].nodes.items(), start=1):
        self.nodeBoxes[key] = wx.StaticBox(nodeTab, wx.ID_ANY, value.name, size=(nodeWidth,nodeHeight))
        # boxSizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.nodeBoxes[key], wx.VERTICAL)
        # nodeInfo = "Node ID: {id}".format(id=value.id)
        # nodeIdText = wx.StaticText(nodeTab, wx.ID_ANY, nodeInfo)
        # nodeStateText = wx.StaticText(nodeTab, wx.ID_ANY, value.currentStateStr)
        # boxSizer.Add(nodeIdText, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        # boxSizer.Add(nodeStateText, proportion=2, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        # NOTE: the next line usually adds the staticBox, not the boxSizer
        # rowSizer.Add(boxSizer, proportion=10)
        rowSizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
        if index % 3 == 0:
            nodeSizer.Add(rowSizer, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
            nodeSizer.AddSpacer((0,25))
            rowSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            rowSizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Why are my boxes resizing and re-laying-out?  I thought to use the box sizer as the horizontal sizer for the row, but that won't work because there are multiple static boxes.

Comment: The code is complicated. And it is not runnable as standalone minimal example, making it very difficult to fire it up and mess around with it. As there are also tons of other oddities (e. g. argument order in ``boxSizer = ``, incredibly convoluted arguments for enumerate, …) you will be less likely to get meaningful help. See [minimal example, MakingSampleApps](http://wiki.wxpython.org/MakingSampleApps).

Comment: Point taken, I've asked this in a new question with a minimal, runnable example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963602/wxpython-staticbox-sizer-resizing-static-boxes

Thanks.