# wxPython — StaticBox Sizer resizing Static Boxes

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

Here is a minimal example of my code that should run by itself -- run as is, everything is laid out how I want, 3 rows of nodes spaced evenly:

```
import wx

def createBoxes():
    outVSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    outHSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    outVSizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
    outHSizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
    sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=3, cols=3, vgap=35, hgap=20)

    box = {}
    boxSizer = {}
    text = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "This is a test")
    for i in range(6):
        box[i] = wx.StaticBox(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "testBox", size=(0,100))
        #boxSizer[i] = wx.StaticBoxSizer(box[i], wx.VERTICAL)
        #boxSizer[i].Add(text, proportion = 1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        sizer.Add(box[i], flag=wx.EXPAND)
    sizer.AddGrowableCol(0,1)
    sizer.AddGrowableCol(1,1)
    sizer.AddGrowableCol(2,1)

    outHSizer.Add(sizer, flag=wx.EXPAND, proportion=15)
    outHSizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
    outVSizer.Add(outHSizer, flag=wx.EXPAND, proportion=15)
    panel.SetSizer(outVSizer)

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, size=(500,500))
panel = wx.Panel(frame)
createBoxes()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

However, when I uncomment the two commented lines and change the line after those to:

```
sizer.Add(boxSizer[i], flag=wx.EXPAND)
```

The layout gets cramped and the nodes overlap vertically, etc.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here, does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the text widget to 6 different sizers is never a good idea. I recommend creating a new instance of `StaticText` for each sizer. The reason for the overlap is that you need to increase your `vgap` when using `StaticBoxsizers`.

Here's an updated version of the code:

```
import wx

def createBoxes():
    outVSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    outHSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    outVSizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
    outHSizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
    sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=3, cols=3, vgap=55, hgap=20)

    box = {}
    boxSizer = {}
    #text = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "This is a test")
    for i in range(6):
        box[i] = wx.StaticBox(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "testBox", size=(0,100))
        text = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "This is a test")
        boxSizer[i] = wx.StaticBoxSizer(box[i], wx.VERTICAL)
        boxSizer[i].Add(text, proportion = 1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        sizer.Add(boxSizer[i], flag=wx.EXPAND)
    sizer.AddGrowableCol(0,1)
    sizer.AddGrowableCol(1,1)
    sizer.AddGrowableCol(2,1)

    outHSizer.Add(sizer, flag=wx.EXPAND, proportion=15)
    outHSizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
    outVSizer.Add(outHSizer, flag=wx.EXPAND, proportion=15)
    panel.SetSizer(outVSizer)

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, size=(500,500))
panel = wx.Panel(frame)
createBoxes()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: plus+1, Twin post, anyone ***grin***

Comment: That was it.  It seems so simple, but I didn't think to increase vgap because it was working with that vgap before the staticboxsizers were in.  I assumed it would just move the start of the vgap down to match the bottom of the static box when it seems like it switched to the end of the staticboxsizer that was shrunk-wrapped to the text up inside the static box -- ugh.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this will be the minimum necessary changes to get some results:

```
    # text = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "This is a test")
    for i in range(6):
        box[i] = wx.StaticBox(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "testBox", size=(0,100))
        # change I
        text = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "This is a test")
        boxSizer[i] = wx.StaticBoxSizer(box[i], wx.VERTICAL)
        boxSizer[i].Add(text, proportion = 1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        # sizer.Add(box[i], flag=wx.EXPAND)
        # change II
        sizer.Add(boxSizer[i], flag=wx.EXPAND)
```

You have added `text` to six different sizers (which is not a good idea). And second, you have to add the `StaticBoxSizer` and **not** the static box to the parent sizer.

The next issue is that for `sizer` the `flag=wxEXPAND` is set, but no proportion. Therefore it will never change size.